# Need someone to explain this code

Tags: arrays, swift, constants

I have been trying to understand this:

```
var arrayOfLabels =
[
    "Hello",
    "Hey",
    "Hi",
    "Howdy"
]

@IBOutlet weak var labelHere: UILabel!

var currentElementIndex = 0

@IBAction func clickForNextElement(_ sender: UIButton) {
    currentElementIndex += 1

    let numberOfElements = arrayOfLabels.count // arrayOfLabels.count = Amount of elements in arrayOfLabels

    let nextElement = currentElementIndex % numberOfElements

    labelHere.text = arrayOfLabels[nextElement]

}
```

I don't get what % does, what the constant "numberOfElements" & "nextElement" does.. I do get a little bit, like i would be able to code something similar to this without understanding it. That's why i need some simple, detailed explanation.

Thank you!

Comment: Ohh it's [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). With every click you increment currentElementIndex by 1, so you can get out of array with it. Modulo prevents from this.

Comment: Reminder operator https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numberOfElements` is set to the number of items in the `arrayOfLabels`.  You have five items in that array so `numberOfElements` is set to 5.

The percent sign "%" is called the modulo operator.  What it does is tells you the remainder after integer division.  So, for example, if you write 5 % 3 what that does is recognizes that 3 will go into 5 only once with a remainder of 2 so 5 % 3 = 2.

In the context of the code currentElementIndex gets increased by one every time you push the button.  So it starts at 0, then goes to 1, 2 etc.

When `currentElementIndex` is less than `numberOfElements` then `currentElementIndex % numberOfElements` will be the same as `currentElementIndex`.  You can check that yourself - for example try when `currentElementIndex` is 2.  2 % 5 says "five goes into two zero times with a remainder of 2" so 2 % 5 == 2 and `nextElement` will be 2

When `currentElementIndex` grows large enough to be equal to a multiple of the number of items in the list, you want it to start over.  The first time that happens is when `currentElementIndex` == `numberOfElements` the values would be 5 and 5.  5 % 5 says "5 goes into 5 one time with a remainder of 0".  So 5 % 5 = 0 and your 'nextElement` becomes zero.

The second time it happens would be when currentElementIndex grows to be 10.  In that case 10 % 5 say "five goes into 10 twice with a remainder of zero"  Again nextElement rolls back to zero.

Try putting print statements into the code and watch how both `currentElemetnIndex` and `nextElement` change when you push the buttons/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a commented version of the code:

```
// create an array of labels
var arrayOfLabels =
[
    "Hello",
    "Hey",
    "Hi",
    "Howdy"
]

// a variable for the label
@IBOutlet weak var labelHere: UILabel!

// initialise a count
var currentElementIndex = 0

// create a function
@IBAction func clickForNextElement(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Add one to our count
    currentElementIndex += 1

    // set numberOfElements to be how many elements are in the array (i.e. 4)
    let numberOfElements = arrayOfLabels.count // arrayOfLabels.count = Amount of elements in arrayOfLabels

    // use the % to work out remainder when dividing our ongoing count by the number of elements 
    let nextElement = currentElementIndex % numberOfElements

    // set the label text to the value of the remainder-th element
    labelHere.text = arrayOfLabels[nextElement]

}
```